# Error 404 on localhost with wampserver

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I've been using wamp for 2 weeks at my work without any problem, but now I've some issues :
`localhost/phpmyadmin` is working well, but
`localhost/` and `127.0.0.1` gives me a `404` error :

> Not Found 
>  The requested URL / was not found on this server.

I already tested the port `80` and it's used by `Apache`.

I have virtual hosts that works well but I can't create a new one anymore, it won't work, I don't know why.

I've searched a lot on internet but all I can find is solution that just does not work for me so if you could help me, that would be fantastic.

EDIT : I just changed my httpd-vhosts.conf, I had a mistake in my new vhosts, so now they work well, but I still have an error 404 on localhost/.

EDIT : Thank you RiggsFolly for the help, I needed to had localhost in my httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: Do you have a correctly configure `\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file, or could that have been changed by some weekly/monthly house keeping your admins do?

Comment: I think it is, here is the only lines I have in the hosts file :
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 aproject.local
127.0.0.1 anotherproject.local
127.0.0.1 again.local
127.0.0.1 project.local
127.0.0.1 andanother.local

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this sounds like the browser is trying to use the IPV6 network but you have not entered the IPV6 loopback address into the hosts file

Amend your hosts file to be

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 other.dev
127.0.0.1 other2.dev

::1 localhost
::1 other.dev
::1 other2.dev
```

The `::1` is the IPV6 loopback address just as `127.0.0.1` is the IPV4 loopback address.

You say you have Virtual Hosts setup, did you also define one, the first one for localhost. Once a Virtual Host is defined the default in `httpd.conf` for localhost is ignored.

So add this to the top of `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Change `c:` to whatever drive you installed WAMPServer onto.

Comment: I just changed my hosts so i have the new line ::1 localhost, I restart wampserver and it didn't change the error 404

Comment: You had better add your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file to your question, maybe there is a mistake in there.

Comment: See additional info about localhost definition